# MySQL Count multiple values in same column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script storing user generated tags ('keywords') in a database for each added video upload, however it places multiple keywords per item in the same keyword column, space separated. I'm not sure how this can be counted correctly. Clearly I'm no expert.

I have a table called '**video**', then within it

```
Vid      keyword  
------   -----------
1        cars 
2        Cars Audi 
3        Boats 
4        Trains  
5        Aircraft
```

Is there a way to set it so the spaced value is counted separately?

If I do

```
SELECT keyword FROM video ORDER BY keyword ASC LIMIT 200
```

It returns

```
1. Aircraft 
2. Boats 
3. Cars Audi  
4. Trains
```

Is there a way to have it return;

```
1. Aircraft
2. Audi
3. Boats
4. Cars 
5. Trains
```

And individually recognize the multiple spaced keywords in certain columns.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this your own, self-written script? If so, change the data structure – normalization is your keyword here.

Comment: Hi, no this is ye ancient PHP video uploader written in php/smarty, looking for a possible workaround before I give in to having it re-written for modern times, which is unknown amount of work for a paid pro. A lot though.

Comment: A workaround would be to 
read the database with a regular SELECT, then EXPLODE the keyword field (each keyword is seperated by a space), write it to an ARRAY (key -> keyword, value -> counter, check if it already exists and if so count +1) and then output the array with FOREACH (sorted descending by value). Not pretty but should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that :

```
 select vid, substring_index(Keyword, ' ', -1)  as item1
 from video
 group by item1 
 order by item1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d5c9/1)

Comment: Thanks, this works! Going to have to see about modernizing the way things are stored though through this script. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

too hard to do so with this table structure...
you need to create a **new table** with `keyword` and `video_id`.. 
this table will have a `primary key` a `foreign key as video_id` and a `keyword field` which should only store **one keyword**

Answer (score 0):

I do not think MySQL alone is capable of doing such a thing. You either need to add some script (I dont know if you are using a script or not) or change the structure of the table.